# Guild Wars: Knights & Dragons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to improve this code to make it look more professional, be loaded quicker and make it cross-browser compatible. Do note that it is not a finished site.  I want to know the best practice for doing certain things before I proceed any further.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div id="menu">
<div id="img">Bild</div>

<div id="gallery">Gallery</div>
<div id="stats">Stats</div>
<div id="members">Members</div>
<div id="groupMe">GroupMe</div>
<div id="knd">K&D</div>
<div id="apply">Apply</div>
</div>

<div id="guildinfo">
<span class="info">Back >></span>

</div>
<div id="wars">Knights & Dragons - Wars

<table id="warslist">

<tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>4.</td>
    <td>7.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td>5.</td>
    <td>8.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>3.</td>
    <td>6.</td>
    <td>9.</td>
</tr>
</table>
<span class="info">Guild info >></span>
<span id="previous"><a href="previouswars.html">Click here to see all previous wars</a>    </span>
</div>

<div id="content">



</div>

<div id="banner"><b>MVP</b></div>
<div id="content2">
<div id="imgHolder"></div>
<div class="fontstyling center">Duplo - Lv 52</div>
<div id="spanHolder">
<span>Class: Assassin</span><br>
<span>Level: 52</span><br>
<span>Vip level: 2</span><br>
<span>Ship level: 29</span><br>
<span>Unlocked exploration areas: 4</span><br>
<span id="arenaRank">Arena rank: (<span id="yellowColor">1</span>) 3696</span><br>
<span>Total contribution: 5624</span>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body { 
        margin: 0px; 
        padding: 0px; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url(img/background.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
        background-size: cover;
}

a { 
        text-decoration: none;
        color: yellow;
}    

#menu {
        width: 316px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 50px;
}

#img { 
        background: url(img/icon.png); 
        background-size: cover; 
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
} 

.menuDivs { 
        width: 70px;
        height: 30px;
        color: yellow;
        background: url(img/brown.jpg);
        font-family: "Arial";
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        float: right;
        margin: 20px 2px -18px 0px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        line-height: 30px;
        border-radius: 5px;
}

#wars { 
        width: 450px;
        height: 170px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: url(img/brown.jpg);
        top: 20px;
        left: 380px;
        position: absolute;
        font-family: "Tahoma";
        font-size: 18px;
        color: yellow;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 30px;
        opacity: 0;
}

#warslist { 
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        color: white;
        margin: auto;
        font-size: 13px;
        text-align: left;
}

.info {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 15px;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: white;

}

#previous { 
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px; 
        right: 15px;
        font-size: 11px;
}

#guildinfo {
        width: 450px;
        height: 170px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: url(img/brown.jpg);
        top: 20px;
        left: 380px;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        line-height: 30px;
}

#content {   /* main content*/
        width: 700px;
        padding: 50px;
        min-height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        margin: 100px auto auto 50px;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Tahoma";
        font-size: 15px;
        border-radius: 9px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
}

#content2 {    /*secondary content (right)*/
        width: 380px;
        min-height: 80%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        top: 380px;
        right: 88px;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 15px;
}

#banner {
        width: 480px;
        height: 150px;
        background: url(img/banner.png);
        background-size: cover;
        top: 320px;
        right: 40px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        text-align: center; 
        line-height: 70px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: black;
        font-family: "Tahoma";
} 

#imgHolder { 
        width: 270px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin: 50px auto 5px auto;
        background: url(img/mvp.png) no-repeat -50px;
        background-size: cover;
}

.fontstyling { 
        font-family: "Tahoma";
        font-size: 15px;
        color: white;
}

.center {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.marginLeft { 
        margin: auto auto auto 80px;
}    

#yellowColor {
        color: yellow;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".info").click(function() {
        if($("#guildinfo").css('z-index') === '-1'){
            $("#guildinfo").css('z-index', '1');
            $("#guildinfo").animate({
                opacity:'1'
            }); //end of animate
        }
        else{
            $("#guildinfo").animate({
                opacity:'0'
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#guildinfo").css('z-index', '-1');
            }, 500);
        }
    }); //end of info function

    $("#knd").click(function() {
        if($("#wars").css('opacity') === '0') {            
            $("#wars").animate({
                opacity:'1'
            }); //end of animate
        }

        else {
            $("#wars").animate({
                opacity:'0'
            });  //end of animate
        }
    });    //end of KND click function

    $("#gallery, #stats, #members, #groupMe, #apply, #knd").addClass("menuDivs");
    $("#spanHolder").find("span").addClass("marginLeft fontstyling");
    $("#arenaRank").find("span").removeClass("marginLeft");
}); //end of doc ready function
```

Comment: Please don't make modifications to the supplied code based on the reviewer's suggestions, as it invalidates their answers.

Comment: Could you please describe what this code does?  It will help with having a better title, which will make this question more attractive.

Comment: I accidently did it before I read it. I will make a new question soon that is more descriptive.

Comment: @DuploW: You could just clarify this question and ask a new question later if you'd like review of updated code.

Comment: editing in the first code now so it doesn't make the answers invalid.

Comment: I've also removed the tabs and made them spaces.  SE's editor doesn't handle tabs well, making it appear that your code is lacking indentation.

Comment: Would you rather recommend writing a bunch of divs with a for loop rather than typing them in the html file? If you take a look at the set of 6 DIVs at the top where the menu items are, I'm thinking about spawning DIVs with a for loop then using an array to fill in the text. Good practice or not?

Comment: @DuploW Usually not a good practise because it won't work with disabled JavaScript. But again, _it depends_ on what kind of site you're doing. For the typical website it's not recommended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HTML:**

1. HTML5 allows omitting the type attribute from link, script and style tags. You can safely remove it from your link tag.
2. You should move jQuery to the bottom of your documents. Otherwise it'll be loaded before your document gets rendered.
3. You use a lot of ID's where you shouldn't. I generally advice avoiding ID's whereever it's possible, because working with classes is easier in terms of CSS specificity.

   Overwriting an ID rule with a class is hard. Also ID's should only be used when you can definitely say there will only be one of these elements on this page.
4. You rarely indent your HTML code. Do it. It allows you to see the structure you're building and leaves less space for mistakes like not closing certain tags.
5. The content inside your ID `spanholder` (again, this should be a class) looks like tabular data. Thus you could use a table for it.

   That said, what about your table with the ID `warslist`. Should this be a table? Why?
6. Use descriptive names. The filenames `css.css` and `javascript.js` are pretty redundant, because the extension already tells you what to expect from this file.

**CSS:**

1. Why do you select both `html` and `body` in your first CSS rule? That only makes sense for your declaration of `height: 100%;`

   This is, what you should have:

   ```
   body { 
       margin: 0;
       background: url(img/background.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
       background-size: cover;
   }

   html, body {
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```

   I removed the units behind `0`, you don't need it for zero values. I also removed the padding declaration, because `body` doesn't have a padding you would reset in all *User Agent Styles* of modern browsers.

   The declaration `width: 100%;` is also not necessary, because both elements are block level elements. Block elements automatically take up the available space.
2. You should declare your basic font rules in the body rule above as well.

   ```
   body {
       /* Using shorthand instead of... */
       font: 14px/1.5 Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;

       /* ...this:
       font-size: 14px;
       line-height: 1.5;
       font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
       */
   }
   ```

   After this you could specifiy some basic rulesets for stuff like headings and maybe a few variations for smaller text (meta data, etc.).

Comment: 1. Does this cause any compability issues in older browsers? I'm afraid that if I remove it it will not work.

Comment: 1. Does this cause any compability issues in older browsers? I'm afraid that if I remove it it will not work.
2. I thought that was only for the javascript document, which I have at the bottom, but I will change it. 
3. I'm using ID's to be able to easily identify things when working with Jquery, don't know a lot about finding a certain element other than using .find() after $("#id/.class"), maybe you know a few tricks?
4. I will try to do that more often. 
5. I could, or could a list do the trick as well? Within warslist I tried to do it with a list and not a table but the list was flowing...

Comment: outside of the div, I wanted it to be 3 columns with 3 list items in each column but I could not figure out how to do that so I decided just to use a table instead. Should I use a list instead and how would I get it to function the way I want it to? 
6. What should I name it after? Since it's the css for the entire site I don't really know what else to name it. Or should I use multiple external style sheets for different parts of the website?

Comment: 1. No, it doesn't. 2. This applies for all scripts. jQuery is a JavaScript library. 3. Using ID's as JavaScript hooks is fine, but I think you're overextending there 5. Depends on what you want to achieve. Try using a list again and do some research. Most things are possible without tables. 6. People usually do something like `style.css` or `sitename.css`. Depends on the project. Splitting up CSS files into multiple ones for production should be avoided, because that also means multiple request being made.

Comment: @DuploW You can post a follow-up question if you improve your code with the tips you get in your review here. Take your time, try some things out and if you're ready, feel free to ask for new reviews.

Comment: 5. I just want it to say the things that are written now on seperate lines, thinking about it I would not have to type <br> after each span which also saves code. So I will use a list there. I guess I could try the other section of StackOverflow to get some help with the other list within #warslist. Yea I'm changing a lot as we speak, will renew my post as I go on. Did you have any more improvements for me at this point?

Comment: @DuploW __Don't__ edit your question with new code here. Post a new question. Editing the post with updated code would mean invalidating already made answers. ;)

Answer (score 6):

A lot has already been said, but allow me to add a few more remarks.

CSS:

- Avoid using classes like 'fontStyling' and 'center'. Classes should relate to the content, not to the styling. I believe the styles from 'fontstyling' should be applied to your body. And that 'center' class, what if you decide tomorrow that you want to align it left? Are you going to have a class `center`with a `text-align: left` or are you going to change it to 'left' and edit both your html and your css? Always try to **keep content and styling strictly separated**.
- Definitely use some sort of **reset or normalize css**. It will make your site look consistent across browsers, and avoids having to reset thing manually (like `margin: 0` on your body). And it takes care of the styles you are bound to forget to reset.
- I see a lot absolute positioning going on. This can be fine in some cases, but it makes it very hard to change things, is a pain to debug cross browser and is bound to cause problems on small screens when you go responsive. Always try to keep your elements in the document flow, and **only use absolute positioning as a last resort**!
- the same goes for all those fixed dimesions. They can be fine and usefull, but they can be a pain when you add content, or a different browser renders your font a few pixels higher. Let the browser do its work and let the content determine the size of your elements. It will make your site scale a lot better. And when you realy have to, try to work with `min-` or `max-` width or height. That way you can control things while leaving space for the content to alter the dimensions.
- There are a lot of background images in there. Could be fine, but hard to tell without seeing them. Note that a lot can be achieved with pure css (gradients, filters, font icons). Also consider working with sprites. I know most users have a fast connection nowadays, but that's no excuses for using a lot af bandwith. We all want a faster internet, don't we?

HTML:

- the `&` is a reserved character inside html. You should replace it with it's entity `&amp;`
- try to use semantic tags, not just divs and spans.

  - A menu is a `nav` which is a `ul` of `a`'s.
  - That table, since it contains 1,2,3,4... that should be a hint. This should be an `ol` split into 3 columns
  - ...
- using background images is fine in most cases, as they usually are just there for styling. In the case of the #imgHolder however, I suppose that contains some guild logo or something. That would be content imo, and therefore require an actual `img`. I always follow the rule: *If a user prints the page, would he want the image on there?* If true, use an `img`, else a background image.
- As already said by others, go easy on the id's. And not each element needs an id or a class. You can also target stuff with selectors like `#menu > div` in stead of adding `.menuDiv` to each menu item.

JS:

- You are adding and removing a bunch of css classes at the bottom of your css. Why would you want to do that? Just do that in your HTML already. That way it is visible on page load, you do not need a reflow, and it is a lot easier to maintain.
- I think you may want to have a look at the jQuery `fadeToggle` function. It would make those click handlers a whole lot easier. And no more need to play with z-indexes and opacity, jQuery does it all for you out-of-the-box.

**Addition:**
As promised, I set up a small fiddle to demonstrate what my code would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/jXy4E/

Note that this is not meant to be a visual replica of the OP code. Just a quick rewrite with the remarks I made taken into account:

- No more styling related classes in the HTML (except for the `.clearfix`, but that is unfortunately currently the best solution that I know of)
- Activated the jsFiddle 'normalize css' option
- Only one fixed position, and as little fixed dimensions as possible. Should be a lot easier to adapt or make responsive.
- Tried to use more semantic html(5) elements.
- Demonstrated some slightly more complex css selectors
- No more adding of classes in the JS
- A much more flexible solution for the click handlers (button 'members' and 'K&D' should work), with the use of `fadeToggle` and `:visible`

I hope it is al clear, but feel free to ask if you want me to explain anything further.

Comment: Some great pointers man thanks. I have changed a lot from the original code already so it looks somewhat better. I have a few questions though:
1. What do you mean by "use a reset or normalize CSS"?
2. What are sprites? 
3. How can I split lists into 3 columns? I have tried but I don't understand how. 
4. I tried the fadeToggle but it didn't seem to work the way it should have. It's hard to explain when you can't really see what I'm trying to achieve with it.

Comment: I managed to split the list into 3 columns, but not with a IE compatible solution however. The other solutions require SO much code that it doesn't seem efficient at all..

Comment: 1. http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/  2. http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ and for 3 and 4 I'll set up a fidde, hang on there

Comment: I'll have a look at those and hanging on for the fiddle

Comment: I finally found the time to set up a fiddle, added it in my answer.

Comment: Your fiddle got my head spinning a bit, don't quite understand the JS in there. Could you explain it further? And when you say "try to have styling and content seperated" do you mean when adding classes and ID's in the HTML? Or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: The JS is fairly basic though. I've added some extra comments in an attempt to explain more in depth. If it is still not clear, please indicate what part it is you don't understand.

Comment: About 'keeping things separated', yes, I mean choosing your class and style names wisely. HTML is for structuring your content and should not have anything to do with the way it is going to look on your webpage, and that includes the classes and id's. Classes like `center` and `yellow` clearly point to the way things are supposed to look, not to what the element actually contains. Try to do some Googling on 'separation of concerns' if you want to learn more.

Comment: So if you click a link that has content linked to it it triggers the target thingy? Why is this a better way? The 'clearfix' class, what is its intention? Didn't seem to do anything when I removed it.

Answer (score 4):

You can start by:

- Standardize indentation. Use 4 spaces, each child element/new scope goes one indent.
- Limit newlines to at most 3. Don't leave too much blank lines.
- Chain if possible. Usually jQuery functions return the same object. In this case, we apply `css` and `animate` to the same `#guildinfo`

  ```
  $("#guildinfo")
    .css('z-index', '1')
    .animate({
      opacity:'1'
    });
  ```
- Cache values when they are used more than once. This is possible as well.

  ```
  var guildInfo = $("#guildinfo")
  guildInfo.css('z-index',1);
  guildInfo.animate({opacity:1});
  ```