# Guild Wars: Knights & Dragons - Version 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have changed a lot from my original code that I posted about a week ago, you can see that here:

[Guild Wars: Knights & Dragons](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49460/guild-wars-knights-dragons)

Now what I need to know is if I improve this code further. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Should I add `<title>` tags to my page to make it more accessible? And also `<meta>` keywords? I have never used it so I'm not entirely sure how it works and why to use them.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pagestyling.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="menu">
        <div id="img"></div>
            <div>Gallery</div>
            <div>Stats</div>
            <div>Members</div>
            <div>GroupMe</div>
            <div id="knd">K&amp;D</div>
            <div>Apply</div>
    </div>

        <div id="guildinfo">
                <span class="info">Back to wars >></span>
        </div>

    <div id="popupwarsdiv"><h3>Knights & Dragons - Wars</h3>

            <ul>
                <li>1/7 80th place</li>
                <li>1/7 80th place</li>
                <li>1/7 80th place</li>
                        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
                        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
                        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
                                <li>1/7 80th place</li>
                                <li>1/7 80th place</li>
                                <li>1/7 80th place</li>
            </ul>

    <span class="info">Guild info >></span>
        <span id="previous">
            <a href="previouswars.html">Click here to see all previous wars</a>
        </span>
    </div> <!--End of popupwarsdiv-->

    <div id="content"></div> <!-- end of content -->


    <div id="content2"></div> <!-- end of content2 -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { 
    margin: 0; 
    background: url(img/background.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "Tahoma", "Arial", "Serif";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: yellow;
}   

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
    margin: 0; 
    color: yellow;
}

#menu {
    width: 316px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#img { 
    background: url(img/icon.png); 
    background-size: cover; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
} 

.menuitems { 
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    color: yellow;
    background: url(img/brown.jpg);
    font-family: "Arial";
    float: right;
    margin: 20px 2px -18px 0px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
    .menuitems:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

#popupwarsdiv { 
    width: 450px;
    height: 170px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: url(img/brown.jpg);
    top: 20px;
    left: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
}

    #popupwarsdiv ul {
        list-style: none;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
        float: left;
    }

    #popupwarsdiv li { 
        width: 110px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 0;
    }

.info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;       
}
    .info:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
#previous { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px; 
    right: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#guildinfo {
    width: 450px;
    height: 170px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: url(img/brown.jpg);
    top: 20px;
    left: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#content {   /* main content*/
    width: 700px;
    padding: 50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    margin: 100px auto auto 50px;
}

#content2 { /*secondary content (right)*/
    width: 380px;
    min-height: 80%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    top: 380px;
    right: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menu").children("div").slice(1,7).addClass("menuitems");

//THE FOLLOWING INFO FUNCTION NEEDS AN INTERNET EXPLORER FIX    

var guildInfo = $("#guildinfo");

$(".info").click(function() {
    if($(guildInfo).css('z-index') === '-1'){
        $(guildInfo).css('z-index', '1');
            $(guildInfo).animate({
            opacity:'1'
            }); //end of animate
}
    else{
        $(guildInfo).animate({
            opacity:'0'
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(guildInfo).css('z-index', '-1');
        }, 500);

    }
}); //end of info function


$("#knd").click(function() {
    if($("#popupwarsdiv").css('opacity') === '0') {         
        $("#popupwarsdiv").animate({
        opacity:'1'
        }); //end of animate
    }

else {
    $("#popupwarsdiv").animate({
        opacity:'0'
    });  //end of animate
}

}); //end of KND click function

}); //end of doc
```

Answer (score 2):

From a once over:

- This:

  ```
  $("#menu").children("div").slice(1,7).addClass("menuitems");
  ```

  should have been set in the HTML, I see no good reason to do this with JavaScript. If you insist on doing it in JavaScript, have `1` and `7` be constants:

  ```
  $("#menu").children("div").slice(FIRST_MENU_ITEM,LAST_MENU_ITEM).addClass("menuitems");
  ```
- Consider using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).
- Consider using http://jsbeautifier.org/, it makes your code more readable, especially the
- Your code is a bit repetitive  in places, for example here:

  ```
  $("#knd").click(function() {
      if($("#popupwarsdiv").css('opacity') === '0') {         
          $("#popupwarsdiv").animate({
          opacity:'1'
          }); //end of animate
      }

  else {
      $("#popupwarsdiv").animate({
          opacity:'0'
      });  //end of animate
  }
  ```

  You are basically calling `.animate()` almost exactly the same, you should find and extract the difference, determine the difference up front and then have one call. For example:

  ```
  var $popupwars = $("#popupwarsdiv"); //Cache this div reference
  $("#knd").click(function() {
      var oldOpacity = $popupwars.css('opacity'),
          newOpacity = oldOpacity === '0' ? '1' : '0';
      $("#popupwarsdiv").animate({ opacity:newOpacity }); 
  }
  ```

You could apply the same in `$(".info").click(function() {`